#  How can I list all of the XAML pages in an assembly?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, assemblies

Can anyone help me to know how to list all of the XAML pages in an assembly ?

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection, of course:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var pages = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(PhoneApplicationPage)));
```

Comment: It isn't quite that easy. A class that inherits from PhoneApplicationPage may not necesarily be a XAML page. It may happen to be implemented completely in code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for pages that were compiled into the xap, then you can enumerate the embedded xaml by using code like the following:

```
string assemblyFullName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ToString();
string baseName = assemblyFullName.Substring(0, assemblyFullName.IndexOf(","))  + ".g";

ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(baseName, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var set = manager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true, true);
foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in set)
{
    if (resource.Key.ToString().EndsWith(".xaml"))
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load(resource.Value as Stream);
        if (doc.Root.Name == "{clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone}PhoneApplicationPage")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(resource.Key.ToString() + " is a Page");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry the downvote was an accidentlal click. It seems to be locked now, and i can not remove it.